# install glassfish3 in Netbeans IDE 7.3?

Tags: java, glassfish-3, netbeans-7

i have installed glassfish3, and have also installed netbeans ide 7.3. Now, i want to add the installed glassfish3 into my server. How can i do this? i don't want to download it again. like, can i give path of my installed glassfish3 in netbeans IDE??

Comment: i know we can add server, but that is not even working, is there any manual way to add glassfish server into netbeans ide?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `Services` tab and right-click on `Servers`, then click `Add Server` and choose your desired server.

[image: add server to netbeans]

Comment: yeah, but i have alreay glassfish server installed, its in my C drive,  but i can't find it in my server lish.. how can i add it manually instead of downloading?

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans comes with GLassfish right? However, have  a look at the following

https://blogs.oracle.com/vkraemer/entry/glassfish_3_1_and_netbeans